# react-native-firebase dependency issue in android setup

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-firebase

I am getting the following error after installing and configuring the react-native-firebase library.

PS. App path is dummy

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   root\android\MainApplication.java:14: error: package io.invertase.firebase does not exi
>   st import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
>
> root\android\MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
>             new RNFirebasePackage(),
>                 ^   symbol: class RNFirebasePackage not found

Comment: Try react native link with the firebase.
Also change the packagge version from thr gradle files

Comment: @madhur already have tried that all ..then after came here.

Comment: Try to follow the steps manually by adding importing RNFirebasePackage() to the android files and the reset cache, this should work

Answer (score 1):

write this line into your `MainApplication.java` file

```
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
```

and follow this steps [RNFirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/android)

hope you will get the solution....

Comment: have done the steps mentioned in the rnfirebase doc. still it did'nt work

Comment: have you import 'RNFirebasePackage' to the MainApplication.java ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes React native not able to load the recent installed module, You need to 
Reset the cache and restart the npm module for enabling the modules in react-native ---> node_modules folder

Follow command

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

And made the bundle file again follow command:

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

Then restart the command it will work

**react-native run-android**

Make sure you have import this module properly in component file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit MainApplication.java file as follows:

1. Import this line

   ```
    import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;
   ```
2. Add ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage() in package list

   ```
      @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());  // Add This line 
      return packages;
    }
   ```

This will solve your issue definitely.